# Is it possible to create an income stream with $50,000?

Tags: starting-out-investing, income

Thank you in advance for your ideas and suggestions! I do not have retirement. I am 60 years old and have $50,000 + to somehow create a positive recuring income stream for myself and future. I am open to anyone's creative ideas, opinions, expertise on way I can do this.

Kind regards,

Bob

Comment: Sure!  It all depends on how much **risk** are you willing to take, and how much **effort** are you willing to make.  If you just want passive income from low risk investments, though, your yearly income will be quite low (like $1000).

Comment: Read my [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109619/investments-that-provide-cash-flow/109622#109622) here and if the idea intrigues you, read this free [Ebook](https://www.preferredstockinvesting.com/PreferredStockInvesting5thEdition.pdf).  It could have used a good editor since it's a bit verbose but there's worthwhile infor for someone looking for income.

Answer (score 4):

Investing is a tradeoff between *risk* and *return*. The more return you want (on average), the more risk you're going to have to take.

That spectrum can range from very low-risk government or corporate bonds that pays 1-2% per year, all the way to highly speculative leveraged investments (e.g. index futures), where you could double or triple your money in a year, but also have the very real risk of losing *everything*.

So if you're planning on *living* off of that income, then you obviously need very low risk (you can't risk having no income, let alone *losing* money). Since $500 - $1,000 a year plus government assistance is probably not enough to live on, you'll need another source of income.

That's about as precise an answer as you can get with that information. If you want to know about specific investment *types* (equities, real estate, etc.) then you can ask more specific questions.